# jQuery wrap closing tag until the same opening tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this markup:

```
<h2>my title here</h2>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
<h2>my title here</h2>
consectetur adipisicing elit quod tempora
```

I would like to select all the content between the closing `</h2>` until the next opening `<h2>` and wrap it as a div with a class, for example:

```
<h2>my title here</h2>
<div class="my-class">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
<h2>my title here</h2>
<div class="my-class">consectetur adipisicing elit quod tempora</div>
```

Comment: you can use `after`.

Comment: Did you try anything so far?

Comment: Yes, I have tried something like this: $('<div class="my-class">').insertAfter('h2') but it's closing that div tag right away

Answer (score 1):

```js
var a = $('body').first().contents().filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType == 3;
}).wrap('<div class="my-class">');

console.log(a)
```

```css
.my-class{
  color:red
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>my title here</h2>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
<h2>my title here</h2>
consectetur adipisicing elit quod tempora
```

DO something like this

Comment: If I have an HTML tag inside of this content it will break a line, is there a way to avoid it?

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('h2').each(function(idx, elm) {

  var $elm = $(elm);
  // select text after h2
  var next = $elm[0].nextSibling;
  var val = next.nodeValue.trim();

  // create div , add text to it
  var $div = $('<div>');
  $div.text(val);

  // remove previously selected text nodes
  next.remove();

  // add divs after h2
  $elm.after($div);
});
```

```css
div {
  color: blue;
  font-size: 1.8em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>my title here</h2>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
<h2>my title here</h2>
consectetur adipisicing elit quod tempora
```

Comment: If I have an HTML tag inside of this content it will break a line, is there a way to avoid it?

Comment: you could just loop over all siblings before `h2` and apply appropriate settings